# Creating bar chart with CSV data python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a CSV with data like

```
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 18:14:58,57,4
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-09-30 20:11:15,1884,90
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"e1.ru",2014-10-04 09:44:21,1146,6
4be390eefaf9a64e7cb52937c4a5c77a,"avito.ru",2014-09-29 21:01:29,48,3
```

I sort this like

```
print(infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.sum())
```

And I got data:

```
address            used_at
am.ru              2014         413071
                   2015         183402
auto.ru            2014        9122342
                   2015        6923367
avito.ru           2014       84503151
                   2015       87688571
avtomarket.ru      2014         106849
                   2015          95927
cars.mail.ru/sale  2014         211456
                   2015         167278
drom.ru            2014       11014955
                   2015        9704124
e1.ru              2014       28678357
                   2015       27961857
irr.ru/cars        2014         222193
                   2015         133678
```

I need to create bar chart like this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

But insted men and women I need to 2014 and 2015 year to every web-site(at axis x) and sum of `active_seconds`(at axis y). 
In example they use np.array, but I have object type series.

I try do this with:

```
width = 0.35
plt.figure()
ax = graph_by_duration['address'].plot(kind='bar', secondary_y=['active_seconds'])
ax.set_ylabel('Time online')
ax.set_title('Time spent online per web site, per year')
plt.show()
```

Should I convert it to np.array or process to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) `DataFrame` for creating columns `2014` and `2015`. Last use [`plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.sum()
                                                                          .reset_index()
print df
              address  used_at  active_seconds
0               am.ru     2014          413071
1               am.ru     2015          183402
2             auto.ru     2014         9122342
3             auto.ru     2015         6923367
4            avito.ru     2014        84503151
5            avito.ru     2015        87688571
6       avtomarket.ru     2014          106849
7       avtomarket.ru     2015           95927
8   cars.mail.ru/sale     2014          211456
9   cars.mail.ru/sale     2015          167278
10            drom.ru     2014        11014955
11            drom.ru     2015         9704124
12              e1.ru     2014        28678357
13              e1.ru     2015        27961857
14        irr.ru/cars     2014          222193
15        irr.ru/cars     2015          133678
```

```
graph_by_duration = df.pivot(index='address', columns='used_at', values='active_seconds')
print graph_by_duration
used_at                2014      2015
address                              
am.ru                413071    183402
auto.ru             9122342   6923367
avito.ru           84503151  87688571
avtomarket.ru        106849     95927
cars.mail.ru/sale    211456    167278
drom.ru            11014955   9704124
e1.ru              28678357  27961857
irr.ru/cars          222193    133678

ax = graph_by_duration.plot.bar(figsize=(10,8))
ax.set_ylabel('Time online')
ax.set_title('Time spent online per web site, per year')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Is it real to add mean above every bar? Because some means too little and It's not clear what changes have occured. Maybe it's argument `yerr` ?

Comment: I try it with `yerr`, but it doesn work - only work comparing `mean` and `std`: `df = infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.mean()
df1 = infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.std()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.bar(yerr=df1, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Time online')
ax.set_title('Time spent online per web site, per year')
plt.show()
`

Comment: Error `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/main.py on line 8, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Comment: Sometimes it happens, if some char is bad copied. Maybe try rewrite code in row `8`.

Comment: Can you say, how can i convert `active_seconds` to hours? I have very large means and I want to divide it `/ 3600`. I write `for string in time['time online']:
    hour = string / 3600.
    round_h = '%.1f' % round(hour, 1)
    graph_by_duration = time.pivot(index='address', columns='used_at', values='round_h')` but i have an error

Comment: if you need `hours`, you can create new column and then use it: `infile['active_hours'] = infile['active_seconds'] / 3600
print infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_hours.mean().round(3)
print infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_hours.sum().round(3)` I think rounding is better after groupby for better accurancy.

Comment: I want to divide sum of `active_seconds`. Because this meaning very small and I won't get normal mean

Comment: Maybe you can divide by 60 - use minutes, not hours.

Comment: this is a divide of `active_seconds`: `infile['active_hours'] = infile['active_seconds'] / 3600`. I want to sum `active_seconds` and after get hours

Comment: So you can use `df = infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.sum() / 3600`

Comment: And can I delete signature `used_at` at the top right corner?

Comment: I try to use `time = infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.sum() / 3600.reset_index(name='time online')` but it doesn't work

Comment: Try `time = infile.groupby(['address', infile['used_at'].dt.year]).active_seconds.sum() / 3600` and then `time = time.reset_index(name='time online')`

Comment: I try to give values to bar charts with `rects2 = az1.patches
labels = ["%d" % i for i in reviews['reviews']]
for rect, label in zip(rects2, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    az1.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, height + 5, label, ha='center', va='bottom')` but it incorrectly passes array

Comment: Yes, I see your new question. But problem is, `matplotlib` is not my friend and now I have no time. Sorry.